# Rudin functional analysis chapter 6 problem 6(a)

Tags: functional-analysis

Problem:Suppose $c_m=\exp\{-(m!)!\}$, m =0,1,2... does the series $\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty}c_mD^m\phi(0)$ converge for all $\phi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

Can somebody give me some hint how to construct a function making this series explode?

Comment: Does $D$ refer to the differentiation operator?

Comment: Yes of course @TheoBendit

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction on the sequence $(D^{m}(\phi (0))$ for a $C^{\infty}$ function. There exists a $C^{\infty}$ function $\phi$ such that $(D^{m}(\phi (0))=e^{(m!)!}$ so the series need not converge.

Comment: But how to construct such a function explicitly?